# Python3: play audio file from given time

Tags: python, audio, time, multimedia

I'd like to have a function with two arguments: file path and start time, that starts the audio file from the given time.
Or whatever else that works the same way.

Is there any library to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/) for the library you're using? There are methods named `set_time`, `set_position`, etc. in the `vlc.MediaPlayer` class you're using, and there are fancier types for doing lower-level stuff than just "create a Player and play a song" as well.

Comment: Thanks, I found it out almost now

Answer (score 0):

I'm auto-answering myself.

I found out this library called libVLC (the library on which vlc is based) that makes what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option for you, you could call some external CLI player that has this feature:

```
import subprocess
def play(path, offset=0):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['myplayer', '--offset=%s' % offset, path],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    pout, perr = p.communicate()
    print(pout)
    if p.returncode:
        raise Exception(perr)
```